# Can I run .exe file in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cmd

Can I run .exe file in windows phone 7 with c#?
I try using System.Diagnostic and Process but I fail. 
Can anyone help me. 
Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the Windows Phone OS and processor architecture is different from the Windows architecture. Executable files may contain operations that are not available on the Windows Phone OS, and the applications run on a sandboxed environment, where they don't have access to all of the device's resources unless you specify so, so that shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch an external application on Windows Phone 7. Much less a native application. Even less an application compiled for x86 architecture (Windows Phone devices use ARM architecture).